# Objective-C: Click Website Button Programmatically

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, xcode, web

How do I programmatically press a button on a website through Objective-C?  Currently, I send an HTTP post to the website and retrieve the `NSData` that is returned:

```
NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postData length]];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://grades.bsd405.org/Pinnacle/Gradebook/Logon.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fPinnacle%2fGradebook%2fInternetViewer%2fGradeSummary.aspx"]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
//[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];
[request setTimeoutInterval:20];
[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

Sending an HTTP post returns the correct `NSData`, but every several weeks the server updates HTTP post properties such as `viewState` and `eventValidation`.  This prevents me from hardcoding those values.  Is there any way to send a press to the website with a username and password using Javascript, or to dynamically input the `viewState` and `eventValidation` parameters?  Here is the website that I am trying to implement this process for: https://grades.bsd405.org/Pinnacle/Gradebook/Logon.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fPinnacle%2fGradebook%2fDefault.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You may write the webservice to get the server's updated HTTP post properties such as viewState and eventValidation.
Once you have these latest properties you can post in your final web request.

Comment: I can get the updated HTTP post properties by checking their value in Google Chrome Developer Tools.  However, the problem is that they when they change, my app stops working.  I need to design it so that it will continue working even if the website changes the HTTP post properties.

Comment: If you can get get the post properties in google chrome, then you can request the same url in NSURLConnection and just check the response, and data, it should contain the same value as in the browser.

Comment: That's right.  My app worked fine when I got the post properties from Google Chrome, so I finalized my app and released it on the App Store.  The problem is that a few days ago, the website updated its post properties and now my app does not work at all.  Is there a way to enter a username and password on the website and press the enter button using Javascript so that my app will work even if the website's post properties change?

Comment: Sorry dude for that you need to make a new version on the app store with these issue fix.

Comment: Yeah, I will release an update once I figure out how to fix these issues.  The problem is that I am not sure how to do that.